# Missing first Match with my current Regex

Tags: c#, regex

The Regex I wrote works great for every situation except for one thing, it misses the first instance of what it should be matching on.

I've searched stack overflow and can't seem to find an exact fit for what I'm trying to accomplish.

The regex I have is `(?<=[\+\-\*\/])-?[.\d]+`
The string I'm trying to identify all valid numbers in is: `6+3*6.3+-2`

I would expect the hits to be "6", "3", "6.3" and "-2" but it misses the first "6". I'm by no means a regex expert, help!

Comment: Could you please update your post to show current code? I have a solution, but I would like to see your implementation first; the look behind is wrong in that Regex.

Comment: You have a positive lookbehind looking for one of the `+-*/` signs, so this obviously won't match the first 6

Comment: What you have only matches number after an operation.

Comment: It's also worth noting the character class `[\+\-\*\/]` can be written as `[-+*/]` to clear up the backslashes

Comment: Your regex can only capture valid numbers preceded by an operator. Use `(?<=^|[\+\-\*\/])-?[.\d]+`

Comment: My code is just this one line var numbers = `code`Regex.Matches(problem, @"[-]?([0-9]*[.])?[0-9]+").Select(x => x.ToString());//Begin Tokeninze"`code`

Comment: I have to use a look-behind to ensure that any "-" that will be matched with a number is preceded by a valid Math Operator

Comment: Are you worried about entries like `2.3.5` or `2..` or `..`, because by your current Regex they are valid. Also, should it match `.2` or `2.` or they are invalid?

Comment: LJISAM's answer worked perfectly, thanks!

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with your RegEx?

Comment: Also what you have matches for example this: +6.3.6

Comment: Brian, I thought you wanted to match *numbers* only before `+`, `/`, `-`, `*` or at the start of a string, but you accepted an answer with a [solution that matches](https://regex101.com/r/yxcUPq/2) 1+ dots, or 1 digits anywhere in the string. So, what is it  you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're super close to a solution. Try this and let us know how it goes.

```
((?<=\+)-?)?([.\d]+)
```

Comment: The one you provided works perfect!, thanks. Also shout out to LJISAM for his version that also works perfectly. (?<=^|[\+\-\*\/])-?[.\d]+

Comment: Awesome! Always glad to help out.

Comment: Note that the first capturing group does not take `/`, `-` or `*` into account, only `+`. But as it is optional, it also matches the dots and the 2 in this string `..@2`

Answer (score 1):

The `(?<=[\+\-\*\/])-?[.\d]+` regex *requires* (as `(?<=...)` is a positive lookbehind) a `-`, `+`, `*` or `/` before an optional `-` and then 1+ digits or dots. You may revert the logic and use a negatvie lookbehind that will make sure there is no char other than `-`, `+`, `*` or `/` before the number.

Speaking about matching a number: `[.\d]+` does not necessarily match a digit, it can match a `.....` string. You should consider changing it to `\d+(?:\.\d+)?` or `\d*\.?\d+`.

Also, you do not have to escape the math operators if you use `[+/*-]` character class.

So, you may solve the issue using

```
var results = Regex.Matches(text, @"(?<![^+/*-])-?\d*\.?\d+")
     .Cast<Match>()
     .Select(x => x.Value);
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3F%3C!%5B%5E%2B%2F*-%5D%29-%3F%5Cd*%5C.%3F%5Cd%2B&i=6%2B3*6.3%2B-2)

**Details**

- `(?<![^+/*-])` - start of string or a position immediately preceded with a `+`, `-`, `*` or `-`
- `-?` - an o[tional `-`
- `\d*` - 0+ digits
- `\.?` - an optional `.`
- `\d+` - 1+ digits.

Comment: Reading the question, this is imho a better answer. +1